# Flutter: Understanding how does a Stateless/Statefull widget layout its child?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout

## TL;DR

How can I know the layout rules of a widget (what size will it request from its parent and  what constraints will it pass to its children) if there is no documentation about it?

## The problem details

I have this very basic app

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
      ),
  );
}
```

I was expecting the `Container` to have width and height of 20 but I got a `Container` that filled up the whole screen.

Reading [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints) article on [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev) about understanding constraints, in its [last part called "Learning the layout rules for specific widgets
"](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints#:%7E:text=Learning%20the%20layout%20rules%20for%20specific%20widgets), they mention how to do this by finding the `createRenderObject` method and then finding the `performLayout` method.

However this `createRenderObject` method is only available for subclasses of `RenderObjectWidget`. For example, navigating through code of `Transform` widget, I find `createRenderObject` that returns a `RenderTransform`, that extends `RenderProxyBox`, which finally implements `performLayout` as :

```
  @override
  void performLayout() {
    if (child != null) {
      child!.layout(constraints, parentUsesSize: true);
      size = child!.size;
    } else {
      size = computeSizeForNoChild(constraints);
    }
  }
```

I can conclude that `Transform` widget will finally take the size of its child due to this line `size = child!.size;`.

But in case of `Container` above, is directly extends `StatelessWidget`. I couldn't find by navigating through its code the methods `performLayout` and `createRenderObject`, I could only find `createElement`,  but I am looking for the `RenderObject` in the render tree associated with the Container and not the element.

## The Question

So the question is how to find this render object associated with a stateless widget/stateful widget in order to know the layout rules that this widget will give to its children and will follow them itself in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a point. I'd say my article is imprecise in that regard.

A widget doesn't need to create a `RenderObject`. It can, instead, use a composition of other widgets that create `RenderObjects` themselves.

If a widget is a composition of other widgets, then instead of looking at the `performLayout` you can simply look at that widget's `build` method to see what it's doing. In the case of a `Container`, this is its `build` method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget? current = child;

    if (child == null && (constraints == null || !constraints!.isTight)) {
      current = LimitedBox(
        maxWidth: 0.0,
        maxHeight: 0.0,
        child: ConstrainedBox(constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand()),
      );
    }

    if (alignment != null)
      current = Align(alignment: alignment!, child: current);

    final EdgeInsetsGeometry? effectivePadding = _paddingIncludingDecoration;
    if (effectivePadding != null)
      current = Padding(padding: effectivePadding, child: current);

    if (color != null)
      current = ColoredBox(color: color!, child: current);

    if (clipBehavior != Clip.none) {
      assert(decoration != null);
      current = ClipPath(
        clipper: _DecorationClipper(
          textDirection: Directionality.maybeOf(context),
          decoration: decoration!,
        ),
        clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
        child: current,
      );
    }

    if (decoration != null)
      current = DecoratedBox(decoration: decoration!, child: current);

    if (foregroundDecoration != null) {
      current = DecoratedBox(
        decoration: foregroundDecoration!,
        position: DecorationPosition.foreground,
        child: current,
      );
    }

    if (constraints != null)
      current = ConstrainedBox(constraints: constraints!, child: current);

    if (margin != null)
      current = Padding(padding: margin!, child: current);

    if (transform != null)
      current = Transform(transform: transform!, alignment: transformAlignment, child: current);

    return current!;
  }
```

As you can see, it is defined in terms of other widgets. And these widgets may also be defined in terms of other widgets and so on. But at some point you will reach the widgets that create the `RenderObject`s.

---

Regarding the reason why the `Container` is not 20x20, it's because, as the article explains, sizes are set by parents. So the `Container`s size is set by the `Container`'s parent, which in this case is the **screen**. And the screen always forces its child to occupy all the available space, in this case ignoring the `Container`'s desire to be 20x20. The fix here is giving the `Container` another parent. One which allows the `Container` to choose its own size. For example, both `Center` and `Align` will let that happen, and that's why you can fix the problem by doing:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    Center( 
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
      ),),);
}
```

As to why the screen forces its child to occupy all the available space: That's just the way Flutter creators decided it should be. If you dig into Flutter's code you will find it there. But it's probably best that you just remember this fact.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer this, I am just learning this layout and rendering thing and its complexity made me miss looking at the build method at the first place :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Meh, don't get too complex yet. here is simplest thing i can explain to you, lets separate an application into 4 different layer.

1. Application -> You can use `MaterialApp` to create an material application
2. Widget Pages -> You can choose between using `Stateless` or `StatefulWidget`, it depends on your need. If you need dynamic, with a a lot of changing states you can use `StatefulWidget` or you can create a static page with `StatelessWidget`.
3. Scaffold -> Widget pages must return a scaffold in order to form an material pages, here you can use `Scaffold`, you can add appBar, fab, body, bottomNavigationBar & etc.
4. Widgets -> Here the widgets can be anything, it's can be an appBar for your scaffold appBar, or ListView, GridView or Custom widget.

So your code must be look like this, kind of

```
/// This block is the first point of your application, this will run your application
void main() {
  runApp(myApp());
}

/// Then you need an material app, this part should return your app
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{

  /// This is very important, both StatelessWidget / StatefullWidget 
  /// always having a build method. It's should returning a Widget. But in this case we will return an material application
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome(),
    ),
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget{

  /// This is home page, it's have Scaffold so the page will using, material guidelines. 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
       body:Container(
         color: Colors.red,
         width: 20,
         height: 20,
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is about how to know the layout rules of any widget, but this does not answer my question.

Comment: Dude you miss the point here `Scaffold` is the one that make your widget appear as your expectation, without Scaffold your widget will not appear correctly

Comment: this is just a demo for the question, I know about the scaffold, did you read the TL;DR ?? please read it to understand my question

Comment: alright then, i have no idea what are you trying to achieve then. good luck